# How to debug a HANDSHAKE_FAILURE when requesting an HTTPS server with ocaml-cohttp Client.post method ? (And why am I getting this error ?)

Tags: unix, ssl, https, ocaml

I wrote the following OCaml code in order to make **POST** requests to an **https** server.

```
open Lwt
open Cohttp
open Cohttp_lwt_unix

try
    let headers = Header.init ()
    |> fun h -> Header.add h "content-type" "application/json" in
    let body = Client.post
      ~headers
      ~body:(body_of_credentials nickname secret)
      (uri_of_project project)
    >>= fun (response, body) ->
      let code = response |> Response.status |> Code.code_of_status in
      Printf.printf "Response code: %d\n" code;
      Printf.printf "Headers: %s\n" (response |> Response.headers |> Header.to_string);
      body |> Cohttp_lwt.Body.to_string >|= fun body ->
      Printf.printf "Body of length: %d\n" (String.length body);
      body
    in

    let body = Lwt_main.run body in
      print_endline ("Received body\n" ^ body)

  with
  | Tls_lwt.Tls_alert e ->
    print_endline (Tls.Packet.alert_type_to_string e);
    exit 1
```

But when executing it with `CONDUIT_TLS=native CONDUIT_DEBUG=true COHTTP_DEBUG=true` I get the following response :

```
Selected TLS library: Native
Resolver system: https://my_server/auth/tokens/ ((name https) (port 443) (tls true)) -> (TCP ((V4 xx.xxx.xx.xxx) 443))
HANDSHAKE_FAILURE
```

I've read all the google results (documentation, ocaml/cohttp/ocaml-tls lists and stack overflow questions) I could find about it, but nothing helps, so I would like to start from scratch here.

How can I get more details about this failure ?

In case it helps, I'm using the following opam configuration:

```
"lwt" {>= "4.1.0"}
"cohttp" {>= "1.1.1"}
"cohttp-lwt"
"cohttp-lwt-unix" {>= "1.1.1"}
"tls" {>= "0.9.2"}
```

EDIT:
As suggested by @ivg, I tried with `CONDUIT_TLS=openssl` but then I get the following error:

```
Selected TLS library: OpenSSL
Resolver system: https://my_server/auth/tokens/ ((name https) (port 443) (tls true)) -> (TCP ((V4 xx.xxx.xx.xxx) 443))
...: internal error, uncaught exception:
    SSL: Method error
```

EDIT²:
As suggested in the following discussion: [github.com/savonet/ocaml-ssl/issues/40](http://github.com/savonet/ocaml-ssl/issues/40) I added an opam pin to `ssl-0.5.5`: `opam pin add ssl 0.5.5` in order to fix this error. Now I am able to post requests to my https server, but not with the pure ocaml implementation of tls.

Comment: first of all, does it work as expected with `CONDUIT_TLS=openssl`?

Comment: No. With this option I get the following error : `internal error, uncaught exception: SSL: Method error`.

Comment: I found this discussion about this error : https://github.com/savonet/ocaml-ssl/issues/40

Comment: Just tried `opam pin add ssl 0.5.5` as suggested and rebuilt. It works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this alert because the handshaking process (authentication) had failed. This alert means, that the peer is not authenticated (either the server or the client) and thus a secure connection could not be established.

To debug the issue, I would suggest first to ensure that everything works fine with conventional tools, e.g., `openssl`, `wget`, or `curl`.

If you're sure that your configuration is fine and this is a problem on the `ocaml-tls` part I would suggest to use the low-level interface of the `ocaml-tls` library. Apparently, `conduit` doesn't expose or use any of the tracing capabilities of `ocaml-tls`, so there is no other choice.

The alert type is projected from two more rich `fatal` and `error` types that bear much more information about the nature of the problem, cf. the [following code](https://github.com/mirleft/ocaml-tls/blob/c8247309f5b21af0d41fbe456c9abb1c4d810edc/lib/engine.ml#L18-L61) that creates an alert and consider possible input values that lead to the `HANDSHAKE_FAILURE` alert.

To access the particular error or alert I would suggest you to use the Tracing capabilities of `ocaml-tls`. There [are examples](https://github.com/mirleft/ocaml-tls/blob/c8247309f5b21af0d41fbe456c9abb1c4d810edc/lwt/examples/echo_client.ml#L18) in the source repository that already enable tracing and should provide sufficient information. I hope those examples will fit into your use case.

Comment: My problem is solved for now (cf. comments above) but this is obviously the right answer to my question. Thx